# A construction using a semiring

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, semigroups

In page number 3 of J.S. Golan's book Semirings and their applications, there is a result which says that

if $R$ is a hemiring and $S$ is a subhemiring of $R$ which is a semiring having multiplicative identity $e$ then the set $R\times S$, on which the operations of addition and multiplication are defined by $$(r,s)+(r_1,s_1)=(r+r_1,s+s_1)$$ and $$(r,s)(r_1,s_1)=(rr_1+rs_1+sr_1,ss_1)$$ is a semiring with unity $(0,e)$.

But I have a question: after $(r,s)(0,e)=(re,s)$, how can we say that $re=r?$

Answer (score 0):

It needs to be posited that $er=re=r$ for all $r\in R$ for this to work.

If this requirement that $er=re=r$ isn't met, it's easy to find counterexamples to the statement even for rings.

Take $R=F\times F$ for a field $F$ and $S=\{0\}\times F$.

$S$ is a ring with identity $e=(0,1)$, and clearly it is not true that $er=re=r$ for all $r$. It doesn't work for $(1,1)$, for example.

---

This construction is usually called the Dorroh extension when $S=\Bbb Z$. In that case, $1r=r1=r$ for all $r$ since integer multiplication is interpreted as repeated addition in the ring's abelian operation.

Comment: But $e\in S$ and so it was said that $S$ is a semiring not $R$

Comment: @Anupam Sorry: I forgot Golan's definition of hemiring and got fooled by the ambiguity of the sentence. I've updated the solution.

Comment: Thus the claim made by the author is not correct! Isn't it?

Comment: @Anupam it was probably just an accident, if so. Even if you copied it verbatim above, it's a little ambiguous. But yeah, unless you find some problem with my example, you can see that e has to be the identity of both rings.